# C File Handling/ Scanning Data From a File

Tags: c

I have a file with one line of text that contains data for 4 students and I'm trying to scan a certain number of characters at a time until I reach the end of file and print all the data into a new file and arrange it properly.
Here is the text inside the file:

> ```
> BaruchComp078045MichalMech090060PinhasElek100090YaelitComp080100DorotiMech100100
> ```

Here's the function:

```
void StudAverage(FILE *in, FILE *out)
{
    char name[7], faculty[5], mark1[4], mark2[4], Avg[5];
    float average;
    while (fscanf(in, "%6s%4s%3s%3s", name, faculty, mark1, mark2) != EOF);
    {
        average = (atof(mark1) + atof(mark2)) / 2;
        itoa(average, Avg, 10);
        fprintf(out, "%s %s\n", name, Avg);
    }

}
```

The problem is that it only scans the data of the last student and skips all the ones before it.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That `itoa` usage is strange. Just fprintf(..."%.0f", Avg);

Comment: You've just got a simple typo with a semicolon at the end of the while

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm still pretty new to files I didn't know I could do that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   while (fscanf(in, "%6s%4s%3s%3s", name, faculty, mark1, mark2) != EOF)
```

Remove `;` in the end.

Comment: WOW I can't believe I missed that. Thanks